# Why is the size of the heap array capacity + 1

Tags: java, data-structures

In this [geeks for geek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-heap-in-java/) article, they initialize the max heap array with a size of capacity + 1

```
public MaxHeap(int maxsize) 
{ 
    this.maxsize = maxsize; 
    this.size = 0; 
    Heap = new int[this.maxsize + 1]; 
    Heap[0] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
}
```

I don't really get why the array size is not `maxsize` instead. Can someone explain this concept?

Comment: Looks like because they're adding a sentinel value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to the heap. A similar question would be, why are they adding a sentinel value to this heap? It probably facilitates some other operations, but it is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in an article

> Note: In the below implementation, we do indexing from index 1 to simplify the implementation.

Reason why they create array of size `maxsize + 1` is because they are operating indices `1..maxsize`.

Reason why they put `Integer.MAX_VALUE` at the beginning of the array is, for example, because in `insert()` method they have `while (Heap[current] > Heap[parent(current)]) ...` which should stop when we reach root of the heap, but they decided not to have any `if`'s and just relied on a fact that when `curent = 1` (root of our heap), this condition will be always false (because `Heap[parent(current)] = Heap[0] = Integer.MAX_VALUE`) and `while` is stopped.